# Backup Exec and SharePoint Gotchas

Tags: backup, sharepoint, disaster-recovery, backupexec

We have Symantec Backup Exec 12.5 installed and configured to back up our SharePoint servers. The farm consists of:

- 1 virtual web/search/Central Admin server (soon to be extended with a second WFE)
- 1 physical indexing server
- 1 virtual SQL Server

We now need to test that we can successfully restore in a disaster recovery situation. Test scenarios are either a particular server or the entire farm going down.

Is this just a matter of clicking Restore in Backup Exec or are there important gotchas to be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have thought you'd be ok, as long as the following are ok when the sharepoint services restart:

- SharePoint install directory (Program
  Files\Common Files\Microsoft
  Shared\web server extensions\12)
- Databases are up and running
- Inetpub directory is up and running
- Connection to Active directory is
  there, for user authentication
  (assumes you are using AD for
  authentication...)

Hope that helps.

Cheers

Nick

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the BackupExec Admin guide, and more specifically, the Symantec BackupExec Agent for Microsoft Sharepoint section? IMHO, that's the best place to start for getting your questions answered. I know it sounds trite for me to say RTFM, but because backups are so important I've read the Admin guide backwards and forwards to make sure I understand how to backup and restore everything in our environment.

Comment: Not trite at all, just wondering about anything missing or common problems that are encountered.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with BackupExec 12.5 and MOSS2007 is that it cannot restore anything that is created by the Web Interface. It can only restore documents that are uploaded (PDF, Word, JPG, etc). When I asked about SharePoint Server 2010 and BackupExec 2010 they said that it still does not have that functionality but they are possibly working on it.

Long story short, make sure you are doing a regular stsadm backup through scheduled tasks in addition to your Backup Exec.